# phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility not detecting anything from PHP 8.0+

Tags: php, phpcs

I am running *phpcs* with the following command:

> ```
> php -d memory_limit=-1 vendor/bin/phpcs -v -p . --standard=PHPCompatibility --extensions=php --colors --runtime-set testVersion 8.1
> ```

However, it is only finding deprecation and errors for PHP 7.4 and below. If I set `testVersion` to any PHP version of 7.4 or below, it works as expected. With the above command, it only finds compatibility issues for 7.4.

To test, I added a new deprecation and removed function from 8.1 and it does not detect them.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you're using a version of `PHPCompatibility` that does not yet know about PHP 8.x features. The current tagged release, as of this writing, is [9.3.5](https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility/releases/tag/9.3.5), which was released on Dec 27, 2019.

It appears that compatibility checks for PHP 8.0, 8.1, and 8.2 only exist in the `develop` branch, and so you will need to specify `dev-develop` in your `composer.json` to be able to run checks for those versions.

This should switch you to the `dev-develop` branch:

```
 composer require --dev phpcompatibility/php-compatibility dev-develop
```

I was in a similar situation (I have code I **know** is not supported in PHP 8.x, but was not being flagged) and switching to `dev-develop` allowed it to be detected properly while using the `PHPCompatibility` standard with `phpcs`.